# select2 v.4 multiselect cloning with jQuery clone() 'recommended' way [destroy] removes behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-select2

Going about cloning a select2 multiselect 'by the book' ([as depicted here](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2928) - `$select.select2('destroy').clone().select2();` )
doesn't really have the desired behavior.

[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8n1ev50m/) shows that calling `destroy()` on the cloned element really destroys the source. Only one clone is possible and the source becomes a simple 'list'.

```
$(".this-one").select2('destroy').clone().appendTo(".container").select2();
```

Is there a way to clone the multiselect while maintaining both the clone and the source in the same select2 format?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i just saw that in this case you have to re-initialize the select2 element that you just destroyed:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8n1ev50m/2/)

```
$(".this-one").select2({
tags:true
})
```

I would love if anyone has a better solution to this approach, it doesn't feel too clean to be honest.